# Remove columns that have NA values for rows - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-cleaning

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows,

```
import pandas as pd

columns=['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F']
index=['1','2','3','4','5','6']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns,index=index)
df['D']['1'] = 1
df['E'] = 1
df['F']['1'] = 1
df['A']['2'] = 1
df['B']['3'] = 1
df['C']['4'] = 1
df['A']['5'] = 1
df['B']['5'] = 1
df['C']['5'] = 1
df['D']['6'] = 1
df['F']['6'] = 1
df

    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   NaN NaN NaN 1   1   1
2   1   NaN NaN NaN 1   NaN
3   NaN 1   NaN NaN 1   NaN
4   NaN NaN 1   NaN 1   NaN
5   1   1   1   NaN 1   NaN
6   NaN NaN NaN 1   1   1
```

My condition is, I want to remove the columns which have value only when A,B,C(together) don't have a value. I want to find which column is mutually exclusive to A,B,C columns together. I am interested in finding the columns that have values only when A or B or C has values. The output here would be to remove D,F columns. But my dataframe has 400 columns and I want a way to check this for A,B,C vs rest of the columns.

One way I can think is,

Remove NA rows from A,B,C

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['A'])]
df = df[np.isfinite(df['B'])]
df = df[np.isfinite(df['C'])]
```

and get NA count of all columns and check with the total number of rows,

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

and remove the counts that match.

Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than delete rows, just select the others that don't have A, B, C equal to NaN at the same time.

```
mask = df[["A", "B", "C"]].isnull().all(axis=1)
df = df[~mask]
```

Comment: I want to remove the corresponding columns. Can we find a way to do that?

Comment: can you add the result you want in the description ?